# How to fill array in c? (assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast)

Tags: c

I am trying to fill a multidimensional array with chars.

The task is: I need to fill 30 names in array, each name could not be longer than 20.

```
char names_arr[NAME_BUF_SIZE][MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
```

So, I wrote such a method:

```
void read_from_input(char arr[][MAX_NAME_LENGTH])
{
    unsigned r = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char tmp[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];

    for (i = 0; i < NAME_BUF_SIZE /*30*/; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < MAX_NAME_LENGTH /*20*/; j++)
        {
            if((r = scanf("%s", tmp) != EOF) && (r != 0))
            {
                arr[i][j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Such a way I would like to fill my array with names.

But the issue is that I get a such warning

```
main.c: In function ‘read_from_input’:
main.c:31:27: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
                 arr[i][j] = tmp;
                           ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the purpose of `tmp` array? Here `arr[i][j] = tmp;` you're trying yo assign the array to the element of second array.

Comment: `arr[i][j]` is a char, and you are assigning to it  `tmp` that is a char array, that is actually a pointer to the first char of the array.

Comment: @Cubo78 aaa, right! Thanks! But, how to fix it? With `memcopy`?

Comment: Given that those are string, consider using strcpy.

Comment: Also, in real application, if you use scanf, always limit the size of the input to avoid buffer overruns (e.g.: "%19s").

Comment: @dash-o do you mean like this `r = scanf("%19s", tmp)`, and such way it will take only 19 chars? or 20 (like from 0...19)?

Comment: Aleksey, strcpy is ok. And about the suggestion above, an array of 20 chars can contain a string long up to 19chars because uone of them is the stringo terminator `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you mean to do:

```
for (i = 0; i < NAME_BUF_SIZE; i++) {
    if((r = scanf("%19s", tmp) != EOF) && (r != 0)) {
        strcpy(arr[i], tmp);
    }
}
```

First of all, in your original code, you're trying to assign `tmp` (`char *`) to `arr[i][j]` (`char`). If `arr` is an array of words, then each `a[i]` will be a word (`char*`) and each `a[i][j]` will be a letter (`char`). Not only that, but that is not the correct way to copy a string.

This is how you should copy a string in C:

```
strcpy(arr[i], tmp);
```

Hope this helped!